# Passing a JSON across python socket to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

I'm using python socket to communicate with JavaScript clients.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

And following the part of JavaScript code,

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7777/");
ws.onopen = function(){
  alert("websocket opened.");
}
ws.onclose = function(){
  alert("websocket closed.");
}
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
  alert(e.data);
}
```

I need to pass a json or a string from the python socket to the JavaScript. Still cant find a way to pass a json. Not any encoding mechanism support for that.

Comment: You can try Juggernaut: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/80/

Comment: @Blender - I would steer clear of Juggernaut since [it has been deprecated by the person that wrote it](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library)

Comment: @D.Shawley How I know at this moment socketio lib is a standart cause it's use whole available transports and choice best one available

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using WebSockets on the client side, your Python code needs to use the [Web Socket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) to send a message to the client.  Take a look at the answers to [javascript - WebSocket Server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839054/websocket-server-in-python) for a number of good alternatives.

*Short Answer:* you can't use `socket` and send messages to a client across a *Web Socket* without implementing the [Web Socket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use the [JSON module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).
And in JavaScript you can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Example from the python doc:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
>>> print json.dumps("\"foo\bar")
"\"foo\bar"
>>> print json.dumps(u'\u1234')
"\u1234"
>>> print json.dumps('\\')
"\\"
>>> print json.dumps({"c": 0, "b": 0, "a": 0}, sort_keys=True)
{"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
```

Example from jQuery doc:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: The serialization above isn't to blame for that I think

Comment: @ChamithMalinda Lol, this not problem python or js this is just you MUST properly implement websocket protocol work on you server side.

Comment: The problem is not the JSON, the problem is sending the string to the client.  You need something to implement [Web Socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) in there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, as a fact you can't send python's object to your client's js. But you can send valid json in the string and parse it on client by jQuery.parseJSON for example.

Comment: I can't send any thing either a string from the python socket.

Comment: @ChamithMalinda I answer to you above what socket it's low level lib for work with tcp/ip protocol it's just can open socket or listen it and send various messages to another. BUT if you need WEBSOCKETS you must implement it on your server side on top of the socket lib. OR you can use allready works frameworks like tornado or gevent wich allready support operations with websockets.